# Which programming language is used in Blender?

Tags: python

As a guy that ALWAYS loved and still loves C++
Does Blender use C++ ?
Some people says Blender and other people says Python

Comment: Blender software source code is c++ (99% sure), Blender API use python (100% sure). [https://docs.blender.org/api/current/](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/)

Comment: [What programming languages can I use in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2580/2217), [Python and C/C++ relationship](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/58946/2217)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender is written in 3 languages: C, C++, and Python.

C - for Blender's [startup/main-loop/shutdown] and most internal functionality, tools, drawing, GUI and editors.

C++ - physics, audio, game-engine and Cycles render engine.

Python - The interface definitions, addons, most format import/export and some tools.

More information can be found here: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/FAQ